# How to publish an app with manage external storage permission on play store

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play, android-permissions, user-permissions

I'm currently working on a video player app and I want to be able to rename, delete and also create a private folder for users, but when I tried submitting the app with manage external storage permission Google rejected it. So is there a way I can go about this that Google won't reject it?

Comment: [Use of All files access permission (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955?hl=en#)

Alternatively you can use SAF to create folders [Create Folder using storage access framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63733975/create-folder-using-storage-access-framework)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.